# Cannot find error with SQLITE statement call

Tags: xcode, sqlite

I am having a problem locating my error.  The code gets through the ID(init) okay and I know the database is loading.  My issue is with the IF(sqlite3_prepare_v2...) statement.  When I run the code this line does not ==SQLITE_OK and it jumps to the end.  ANy help is appreciated.  Thanks.

```
@implementation CityState

static CityState *WDdatabase;

+(CityState *)WDdatabase {
    if(WDdatabase == nil) {

        WDdatabase = [[CityState alloc] init];
    }
    return WDdatabase;
}



- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSString *sqliteDB = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CityAndState" ofType:@"sqlite"];

        if(sqlite3_open([sqliteDB UTF8String], &WDdatebase) != SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database");
        }
    }
    return self;
}


-(NSArray *)getAllCities {
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM Test_Table";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(WDdatebase, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
       }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    return returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Objective-C does not do static class variables as you are attempting, and the symbol `WDatabase` (I'm assuming the typo is just here on SO, not in your code) is actually a class identifier instead of your static variable. To implement a singleton, you will need a file-scope variable (outside of the @implementation block) (and I recommend you name it starting with an underscore to clarify when you are accessing that and when you are accessing the class method. So basically, the call you are failing is likely because you are passing a *class object* instead of your var. Once you have setup the static var properly.

The proper syntax then for accessing a "class variable" (which end up being just a file-scope/statically-stored variable, by virtue of Objective-C's C soul), is to send a message to the class object:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2([CityState wDdatebase], [query UTF8String], ...
```

Further, and just to be pedantic; if you are not using any of NSString's features and only need UTF8 (or "C-style") strings, you can use them just as you would in C:

```
-(NSArray *)getAllCities {
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    char query[] = "SELECT * FROM Test_Table";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2([CityState wDdatebase], query, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
       }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    return returnArray;
}
```